# dotnet core 2.0 - Logging Custom Events using LoggerMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I've been trying to replace the TelemetryClient in my code with the LoggerMessage pattern. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

I could not find any way to log Custom Events in this pattern. Is there a way I can directly log Custom Events using the AppInsights Middleware provided in Asp .Net Core 2.0? Or is it alright if I stick to Telemetry Client and ignore the performance advantages claimed by LoggerMessage?

Comment: I looked into this and I'm not sure what the problem is with the LoggerMessage but it's seems for really high performance applications. It saves a boxing operation so unless you're seeing > 100 transactions per second I wouldn't worry about it.  "premature optimization is the root of all evil",  but good on you for not being complacent and a [cycle eater](http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-black-book/#chapter-4-in-the-lair-of-the-cycle-eaters)

Comment: still looking for an answer?

Comment: I couldn't find an alternative to TelemetryClient, because TelemetryClient is specific to AppInsights and CustomEvents are specific to AppInsights. So, I went ahead with the TelemetryClient itself. But, would love to know in case there is a solution to this.